# Recursion: integrating complex condition and order by rank

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Existing XSLT-code need to be enhanced by following conditions.

1 - Along with recursion algorithm add checking that each comparing line (element) has:

- the attribute status=0
- and attribute status2 is null (here it means that there is no attribute status2 within the element, actualy)
  (a chain can only be created if these two conditions are true)

2 - Rank order. All restored (or restoring) chains finally must be ordered by the 'rank' attribute
(it may match with a native recursion, but sometimes not. Anyhow 'rank' attribute has higher priority.
Rank has no stable nomenclature (like 1-2-3-4) but its chain can be calculated by comparing 'more'-'less'. (1 < 3 < 7).

**source code**

```
<A>
  <X id="top"                         text="first"  text2="*"     status="0" rank="1"/>
  <X id="middle"  id-parent="top"     text="second" text2="**"    status="0" rank="3"/>
  <X id="bottom"  id-parent="middle"  text="third"  text2="***"   status="0" rank="6"/>

  <X id="bottom2" id-parent="middle"  text="fourth" text2="****"  status="0" rank="2"/> <!--note rank! bottom and middle should be switching because "bottom2 has a "higher" rank-->
  <X id="bottom3" id-parent="middle"  text="fifth"  text2="*****" status="2" rank="6" status2="any-value-make-its-status-not_null"/>
</A>
```

**XSLT transformation**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="X" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="X">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Xs">
            <xsl:call-template name="XATT">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentX" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="X" select=".">
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$Xs[node()]">
                <xsl:attribute name="chain-text">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$Xs/X">
                        <xsl:if test="position() ne 1"><xsl:text> | </xsl:text></xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@text, ' ', @text2)"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="$Xs/X">
                    <xsl:attribute name="level-{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="concat(@text, ' | ', @text2)"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="XATT">
        <xsl:param name="currentX"/>
        <xsl:param name="X"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$currentX/@id-parent">
                <xsl:call-template name="XATT">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentX" select="key('ref', $currentX/@id-parent)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="X">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', $currentX/@id-parent)"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$X"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$X"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AcskR

inteconnection [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKMCv.jpg)

**desired output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><A>
  <X id="top" text="first" text2="*" chain-text="first *" level-1="first | *"/>
  <X id="middle" id-parent="top" text="second" text2="**" chain-text="first * | second **" level-1="first | *" level-2="second | **"/>
  <X id="bottom" id-parent="middle" text="third" text2="***" chain-text="first * | second ** | third ***" level-1="first | *" level-2="second | **" level-3="third | ***"/>

  <!--new conditions are clearly visible on the following lines-->
  <X id="bottom2" id-parent="middle"  text="fourth" text2="****" chain-text="first * | fourth **** | second **" level-1="first | *" level-2="fourth | ****" level-3="second | **"/> <!-- bottom and middle are switching because of 'rank' -->
  <X id="bottom3" id-parent="middle"  text="fifth"  text2="*****" status="1" rank="6" status2="any-value-here-make-its-status-not_null"/> <!--nothing happens with this line because of 'status' and 'status2' attributes  -->
</A>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording obscured the problem. You need to fold the hierarchy (expressed with `@id` and `@id-parent` attributes) and then sort the path by `@rank` attribute.

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet (with EXSLT extensions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:key name="X-By-id" match="X" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="X-By-parent-id" match="X" use="string(@id-parent)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fold-rtf">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="fold"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="folded-tree" select="exslt:node-set($fold-rtf)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="X[@status=0][not(@status2)]/@*[last()]">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select=".."/>
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$folded-tree">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('X-By-id',$current/@id)">
                <xsl:attribute name="chain-text">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                        <xsl:sort select="@rank"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=1"> | </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@text,' ',@text2)"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>                
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                    <xsl:sort select="@rank"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="level-{position()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@text,' | ',@text2)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>                
            </xsl:for-each>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/|*" mode="fold">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('X-By-parent-id',string(@id))" mode="fold">
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs:

```
<A>
  <X id="top" text="first" text2="*" status="0" rank="1" 
     chain-text="first *" level-1="first | *" />
  <X id="middle" id-parent="top" text="second" text2="**" status="0" rank="3" 
     chain-text="first * | second **" level-1="first | *" level-2="second | **" />
  <X id="bottom" id-parent="middle" text="third" text2="***" status="0" rank="6" 
     chain-text="first * | second ** | third ***" level-1="first | *" level-2="second | **" level-3="third | ***" />

  <X id="bottom2" id-parent="middle" text="fourth" text2="****" status="0" rank="2" 
     chain-text="first * | fourth **** | second **" level-1="first | *" level-2="fourth | ****" level-3="second | **" /> <!--note rank! bottom and middle should be switching because "bottom2 has a "higher" rank-->
  <X id="bottom3" id-parent="middle" text="fifth" text2="*****" status="2" rank="6" status2="any-value-make-its-status-not_null" />
</A>
```

**Do note:** the use of `node-set()` function for a two step transformation, the change of context for using `key()` function with another input document, forcing the string casting of the key because there are special rules about nodesets as keys and also because I wanted to use an empty string key...

**Advice:** all this could be translated into a few lines of XSLT 2.0+

Comment: My gratitude for a code and advice! I’ll mindfully scrutinize both.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921582/change-patterns-priority-or-revise-the-code Added one more pattern to your code. It deletes all nodes that do not form recursive chains. But there heppened a question on optimization. Maybe you will have your own opinion about this. One of the options, it seems to me, is to solve the problem without the DELETE pattern, and initially only output the nodes that form the chains.