# Change pattern's priority or revise the code?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is a code which, in fact, gives the correct output. But the question is about optimizing internal processes. They, conditionally, can be divided into 2 parts.

- MAIN  algorithm (set of codes which create relation chains)
- DELETE pattern  (removes unnecessary nodes, which do not meet the conditions)

Patterns' execution priority as i can rate on tests is 
1-[MAIN] then finally 2-[DELETE]. But the thing is, the opposite order 1-[DELETE]  then 2-[MAIN]  would be, as i guess, a more effective solution. 
In this case, only the necessary nodes that form the chains would remain for MAIN-processing (so then inner additional-checking condition also will no longer be needed). But for now, MAIN  algorithm is forced to do an extra, unnecessary computation. 
I tried to use additional priority attribute to the patterns, but it seems that it didn't change anything (because, as i understand, these two templates don't conflict with each other).

XSLT-code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
  <xsl:key name="Object-By-id" match="Object" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="Object-By-parent-id" match="Object" use="string(@id-parent)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="fold-rtf">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="fold"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="folded-tree" select="exslt:node-set($fold-rtf)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Object[not(@status='0')]"/>      <!-- [DELETE] pattern -->

  <xsl:template match="Object[@status=0]/@*[last()]">  <!-- [MAIN] -->
    <xsl:variable name="current" select=".."/>
    <xsl:copy/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$folded-tree">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('Object-By-id',$current/@id)">
        <xsl:attribute name="chain-text">
          <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:sort select="@rank"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=1"> | </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@text1,' ',@text2)"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
          <xsl:sort select="@rank"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="level-{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@text,' | ',@text2)"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/|*" mode="fold">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Object-By-parent-id',string(@id))" mode="fold">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*In sum i've got following questions:*

a) In spite of the attempt, is there any kind of compulsory enforcing to change the priority of the template execution plan?

b) Or any other considerations?

here is sample bar just to demostrate how many computation cycles can be potentially saved.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1y5

Comment: Can you run the transformation twice?  First for the deletion and second for the Main.  This would involve two XSLT files.

Comment: It's possible, for sure. But I expect that there should be (and not even one) way to do it within single file. This would certainly be a more elegant solution.

Comment: The same way you use predicates `[@status=0]` and `[not(@status=0)]` in default mode, you should use those in any other pattern matching (`"fold"` mode and keys). Or filter first, then hierarchical folding, and finally copying with data aggregations.

Comment: XPath 1.0 data model views an XML document as a tree.  Your XSLT codes works against the entire tree to produce output.  It does cannot change the tree itself.  So, you can't delete things in the tree.  You can only not output them (Which seems like deleting.).  Any xpath you use will search the whole tree.  For example, ancestor-or-self::* will always examine all the relevant tree nodes, even if you are not out putting them.

That's why I suggested having two XML executions.  I do it all of the time.

Comment: It works in this way (4 conditions added) https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AcskX And even in a shroten version, if leaving these conditions only in "identity transformation" https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivJs2